# How to put cpuUsage value in variable through os-utils provided by node js

Tags: javascript, cpu

```
var os  = require('os-utils');
os.cpuUsage(function(v){
    v = Math.round(v*100);
    console.log( `os-utils get CPU Usage : ${v}%`);
    return v
});
var cpuUsage = os.cpuUsage(v()); 
console.log('what is that '+ cpuUsage); console.log(v); // undefined
```

I want to put the value in a variable and declare it as a global variable.
I can't understand the asynchronous way. Please help me how to set up the callback function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.